# Replace inner double quotes in a string in an array

Tags: ruby, string, escaping

I have strings in an array:

```
["foo","bar","foo"bar"baz"]
```

I am using `eval` method to form an array with this string, but the inner double quotes are not escaped:

```
eval('["foo","bar","foo"bar"baz"]') # => SyntaxError
```

Is there a way to escape only the ones inside an array element?

Comment: Have you tried to write a pattern for that? Please share your attempt(s).

Comment: Could you tell, what you want to get as a result?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am trying this https://repl.it/CdvP/1

Comment: @SergeyGuide something that i can use in eval to create a ruby array `["foo","bar","foo\"bar\"baz"]`

Comment: so did you try the backslash?

Comment: @maxpleaner backlash put the backlash with all double qoutes, I want to escape the inner ones only. `"hello "World"."` -> `"hello \"Workd\"."`

Comment: How did you ever get into this situation? I.e, why would you not just manually escape the inner quote?

Comment: @maxpleaner Fixing someone else's code. Cant change the whole implementation (which definitely needs a revamp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can try something like

```
eval('["foo","bar","foo"bar"baz"]'.gsub(/(\w)\"(\w)/, '\1\"\2'))
```

if I got what you have meant

Comment: Or `.gsub(/\b"\b/,'\"')`

Comment: Yeah, this is much more elegant solution

Comment: I think it won't fix all the cases, unfortunately. What about `'["foo","foo"b ar"baz",""an"t"on""]'`?

Comment: Thanks @SergeyGuide

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your solution and
I am testing with

`eval('["foo","bar","foo "bar" baz"]'.gsub(/\b"\b/,'\"'))`

and it is not working. Both of the solutions, unfortunately.

Comment: The problem is that it cannot be fixed in 100%. What if the field has `","` *inside*? There is no 100% safe way to fix that text. It should be fixed before you get it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What would be your preferred way to include space characters before and after the qouted text.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help further, it has no right solution.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I've added a solution below which seems to be correct for all possible variants.

Comment: @SergeyGuide: Sorry, it might work in 95%, but there will still be cases when it won't work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, can you give a negative example?

Comment: *What if the field has `","` inside?* Here is one: `["foo",""Cool","Great" are synonyms"]` where the second item must be `"\"Cool\",\"Great\" are synonyms"`.

Comment: It will be rearranged into `["foo", "\"Cool", "Great\" are synonyms"]` without any exception.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for all possible variants. This would fix all quotes except of appearing near commas and brackets

```
.gsub(/(?<!\,)(?<!\[)(?<!\])\"(?!\,)(?!\[)(?!\])/, '\"')
```